# Can an in-app object only be posted through an opengraph action?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have a page inside a facebook application that is an opengraph object, when I post a custom  action on this object to facebook from my app it is posted right, but when I use a facebook social plugin such as like and like that object it is not posted as that object but instead the object of my facebook application is posted on the timeline... so my question here is Can an in-app object only be posted through an opengraph action?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, new OpenGraph object will be created or data will be updated for existing one once Facebook linter crawl your page to get data this will happen in several cases:

- OpenGraph action referencing object published
- Like button clicked for specific URL
- Link to your page shared on Facebook (in direct way or via any [dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) using `link`, etc).

Your Like button is probably linked not to your real application URL but to URL within Facebook resulting in different Pages parsed by Facebook on Like Button click and OpenGraph action publishing.

I assume that your like button pointing to Application Tab Canvas or Application Page since links to regular application's canvas parsed correctly by Facebook.

**Update:**
Seems like the issue with OpenGraph tags is related to the fact that your application returning `404` (**Not Found** status code) for URL you provided and only returns data for HTTP (but not HTTPS) requests. If error code is returned the cached data is preserved and will not be updated until correct status code returned.

**Update 2:**
As you've provided real URL it's became clear that you get details for your application instead of actual page because of redirect for all unauthorized users, which lead to inability to rich the real OpenGraph data by Facebook linter.

BTW, You should be aware that **every OpenGraph object MUST have publicly accessible URL**.

Comment: yes it does point to e.g url http://apps.facebook.com/appnamespace/eg.php?id=5

does that mean facebook wont get its object details.. cause we I pass it through lint it get the details of my app and not the ones that are mentioned on this page.

Comment: @user1064950, seems like your app resulting in 404 for that URL (at least for me and Facebook), check it with [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fappnamespace%2Feg.php%3Fid%3D5). I've updated my answer to provide a bit more details on that

Comment: @JScripter: that is not my actualy url I just wrote that as an example.

Comment: @user1064950, Facebook generally follow Canvas URL in case you sharing/liking link to the Application Canvas in Facebook (but this isn't the case for Page Tab apps), just make sure debug tool fetches the correct data for URL you use and ensure it's the same URL as in OpenGraph object you refer in action

Comment: that is the problem that the debugger tool is not fetching the right data, it fetches the object of my app and not the object inside my app which the link points too.

Comment: Until we can see a real URL to test with, there is only one way - guess. Help us help you.

Comment: well here it is https://apps.facebook.com/fbviralvideos/videos.php?autostart=true&id=6

Comment: @user1064950, Oh, you just hit the redirection to OAuth Dialog for every non-authorized visitors (which linter is). I've updated my answer to state this.

Comment: if i make it publicly accessible then how will I get the user to join my aap before viewing the page... and the question that comes to my mind is .. that when this url is not publicly accessible then how does facebook show the rigth object when i publish the object through my app ... I am guessing its because of my app token and facebook button doesnt have that... what do you suggest I should do to get this done, make my own like action?